# torrent magnet link applications (ubuntu 14.0)

Tags: 14.04, firefox, deluge

how do i set deluge as my default magnet link application I am completely lost. I've tried going into my Mozilla preferences but i cant find deluge when I am searching for the application please help.

Answer (score 1):

Run :

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/defaults.list
```

In the resulting Gedit file, change the `torrent` or Magnet Link files to open with `deludge.desktop`.
Now look for "x-scheme-handler/magnet", it may not be there but just make sure not to enter duplicates:
The line should look like this:

`x-scheme-handler/magnet=deluge.desktop`

I have this problem, I added this line to the file and now it is solved.